# In Android Passing dynamic String List values into the spinner is not visible in bottom sheet layout?

Tags: android, spinner, bottom-sheet

I'm creating `Spinner` inside the `Bottom Sheet Dialog`, here I get the spinner Values from the size, size is a String. I get this string from the firebase realtime database. I open up the bottom sheet layout while the user clicks the Recyclerview items. I tried size with static values(`String size="S,M,L,XL,XXL";`); this is working well, but if get the size values like this(below the code) Spinner items like this[image: screenshot]. what went wrong here?

```
String size="";

        @Nullable
                @Override
                public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
                    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_layout,container,false);


    databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Product_Details");



            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        Model_upload mp=dataSnapshot1.getValue(Model_upload.class);

                        if(itemid.equals(mp.getId()))
                        {

                            size=mp.getSize();

                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });            

                    String[] sizeslist = size.split(",");

                    ArrayAdapter<String> adaptersize = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sizeslist);
                    adaptersize.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spinner.setAdapter(adaptersize);


                    return view;
                }
```

Comment: Please add your crash logs

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this part to another method:

```
String[] sizeslist = size.split(",");

ArrayAdapter<String> adaptersize = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sizeslist);
adaptersize.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adaptersize);
```

and after this line `size=mp.getSize();`

call this method.

Or you can just move these lines under `size=mp.getSize();`

Comment: Thank you, just before I found out my mistake, I added my code below, thank you

Answer (score 0):

My mistakes were I assign the spinner values outside the `addValueEventListener()` method this is working fine for me

```
String size="";

            @Nullable
                    @Override
                    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
                        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_layout,container,false);


        databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Product_Details");



                databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                        {
                            Model_upload mp=dataSnapshot1.getValue(Model_upload.class);

                            if(itemid.equals(mp.getId()))
                            {

                                size=mp.getSize();

                                String[] sizeslist = size.split(",");

                        ArrayAdapter<String> adaptersize = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sizeslist);
                        adaptersize.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        spinner.setAdapter(adaptersize);

                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });            

                        return view;
                    }
```

Comment: Thank you for choosing my answer as the accepted answer :)